# Hidden DIV links making others unclickable

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello and thanks for reading. I am having an issue where a hidden div with `opacity: 0;` still allows the user to interact with clickable elements of div.  This makes it so the user can't interact with clickable elements of that that hidden div that overlap. I would typically tackle this by using 
`position: absolute; pointer-events: none;`
but that results in the opposite taking place in which the hidden div's links are no longer clickable. I have double-checked my z-index and its looks correct but the issue persists. Furthermore the hidden div seems to ignore the toggle effect applied to it and just pops up with any animation.

Click the checkbox to activate the hidden div:

http://codepen.io/gmrstudios/pen/jyoZvL

Comment: What is your desired behavior? Which elements can you not interact with that you should be able to? Which element is the hidden one?

Comment: I ask because in the codepen example, it's not obvious what the problem is. It seems to be functioning fine.

Comment: @JakeParis trying clicking on "Gerard".  While it looks like its business as usual you are actually clicking on "Change Priority" which is part of the hidden DIV.  Also if you hover to the left and right of "Gerard" you will notice that the other links from the hidden div can be activated.

Comment: The desired behavior is to be able to not be able to interact with the links in the hidden div until they are shown. Whil also being able to click on link associated with the Tech's name. Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow: hidden;` on the td.tg_admin element.
And please use tg_admin as a class, ids are meant to be used only once.

Comment: This ends up partially blocking the display of the hidden DIV.

Comment: Actually, applying `overflow: auto;` to hidden the hidden div and `overflow: hidden;` to the td_admin element doesn't work. I updated the codepen so show what happens.

Comment: I can't see you changing the value of overflow: hidden anywhere in your code. You can set the style with jQuery...

Comment: It's there `#td_admin {
  height: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 19px;
  perspective-origin: 24.5px 33px;
  transform-origin: 24.5px 33px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(224, 224, 224);
  font: normal normal normal normal 13px / normal "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  padding: 17px 20px 17px 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
}` http://codepen.io/gmrstudios/pen/jyoZvL

Comment: So...?
`$("#type-2 a").click(function(e) {
  var selector = $('.' + $(this).attr('id'));
  selector.toggle("slow").css('overflow: hidden');
  $('div.togg').not(selector).hide();
});
`You will have to forgive my ignorance when it comes to this sort of thing.

Comment: well no you have to set the overflow property of the td element. Also with a "." you select classes and with a "#" you select ids. Please update your codepen to use classes.